# File not found if specify "/" in beginning.

Tags: php, apache

I start working on some existing code. This code uses manual routing and it is already running live so I can not change coniguration files.

Problem is when I run this code in my local server, no files can include because of **"/"** in beggining.

Example: `<img src="/images/header.png">`

I can not find **header.png**. but if I remove "/" like `<img src="images/header.png">` I can get.

I can not change code because it runs successfully on live server. I think I need to change some apache configuration.

I am using **apache 2.0**.

Please guide me guys. :(

Comment: Do you have the same directory structure in both live and local?

Comment: Well you should ask a clear question, so that we can answer that!

Comment: yes directory structure is same. sorry for delay

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because of the  folder structure. With - `/images/header.png` it will look in at the root folder. And if `/` is removed then it will try to access it on the current folder.

Comment: That just explains what the codes does, but doesn't answer any question. Which is also kinda difficult, since OP didn't asked a specific question

Comment: @Rizier123 i think OP asking for the problem with this code.

Answer (score 0):

It could be you have used `<base>` tag in your html page with url ending with `"/"`. So, adding a `"/"` before the image path renders the path invalid